# How to update Ubuntu's logcheck frequency?

Tags: cron

I have installed logcheck through `apt-get`, and while in the process of refining and testing, I was not able to find where it is being executed from.

I saw several online articles explaining that in its installation, you're supposed to create an entry in your crontab. However, after installing the package, no crontab entry was created on my user or my root's crontab, but still emails are going out every hour.

I checked the contents of the manpage and I checked the configuration files, but I could not find any reference as to where can I configure the frequency for logcheck.

How is that done?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If you want to know where are the files executed when logcheck is run you can use `type logcheck`

Comment: @M.Becerra thanks, but not exactly. I want to know where they are executed _from_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schedule is in the `/etc/cron.d/logcheck` file.

Below is the content of the file:

```
# /etc/cron.d/logcheck: crontab entries for the logcheck package

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

@reboot         logcheck    if [ -x /usr/sbin/logcheck ]; then nice -n10 /usr/sbin/logcheck -R; fi
2 * * * *       logcheck    if [ -x /usr/sbin/logcheck ]; then nice -n10 /usr/sbin/logcheck; fi

# EOF
```

So it runs after reboot and at 2 minutes every hour every day.

I suggest not to change the frequency but rather identify log events you don't want to receive and add them to a logcheck ignore folder like /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/. Logcheck already has a good set of pre-installed rules, but you can modify them to your liking.

Comment: I don't think this is enough. It is a good clue for a person who knows how to set a cron job. Please add some more detail on how to alter this file for a specific frequency.